# How to pass MutableList of object via intent in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I have my data class as

```
@Parcelize
data class Workouts(val id:Int ,val name:String,val image:Int,val time:Long):Parcelable
```

and in one activity I have initialized mutuable list and also added some data to the MutuableList

```
   val listRandom= mutableListOf<Workouts>()
     listRandom.add(some datas............)
```

Now I have used Intent to pass the **listRandom** to next activity

```
 val intent =Intent(this,StartWorkout::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("workoutlist",listRandom as Parcelable)
```

Now in next activity I am trying to receive data as

```
 val randomWorkout =intent.getParcelableExtra<MutableList<Workouts>>("workoutlist")
```

so the error comes while receiving the data from intent it says *Expected Parcelable but found MutuableList*

So what I am trying to do is just pass the list of object so Is there any way to do this in other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert your `mutableListOf<Workouts>()` to ArrayList like below:

```
val listRandom= ArrayList<User>()
val intent = Intent(this, StartWorkout::class.java)
intent.putExtra("workoutlist",listRandom)
```

Next Activity:

```
val randomWorkout : ArrayList<User> = intent.getParcelableExtra("workoutlist")
```

it will work.

Comment: It says 
Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun <T : Parcelable!> getParcelableExtra(p0: String!): T!
Please specify it explicitly.

Answer (score -2):

Use `putParcelableArrayListExtra` with `ArrayList`

```
val listRandom= ArrayList<Workouts>()
val intent = Intent(this, StartWorkout::class.java)
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("workoutlist",listRandom)
```

And get it with

```
val list=intent?.getParcelableArrayListExtra<Workouts>("workoutlist")
```

Comment: The other one who isn't showing how to convert in the first place